# how to validate a form to prevent from double entry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have create one student registration form and i want to validate it in this way that if any student information is entered(register) here then the same student can not be register again.

here i take fields 
First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, Father Name, Mother Name, Date of Birth, Address etc.

here i am confused that how can i validate it that same person can not be register again. because in this world it is possible to have a more than one person with the same name, same father name, same date of birth and same place etc...

so please give me advise how can i validate it...

Answer (score 3):

With those fields, you can not validate the unuqueness of the record. you need to have some field which is unique.

You may consider adding **EmailAddress** or a **username** to your registration form and the databse table. When user submits the form, you check whether this email /username is already exist in the table and if it does not existin, save it, else show the message to user saying that record already existing for this username/email.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about a high school as an example, a registration system would *have* to obtain a unique identifier of a person in order to guarantee uniqueness. This is why a social security number is required when enrolling in USA schools. It represents the only piece of information which uniquely identifies one person from another.

If you only want to be *reasonably* sure, then you can collect, for example, their name, the last four digits of their social security number, and their birthday. The combination of those three things is a reasonable guarantee of uniqueness.

In the case where you don't collect an *actual* unique identifier from the person, the more fields you add together about the registrant, the better chance you have at distinguishing them from a similar, but different user.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom validator, so in the server, you can call to the db and check if the user already exists. In that case, set the variable args.IsValid = false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k

And yes, I would also recommend you having a unique field such as email, etc.